# Trouble with installing the fastman package on a remote compute

Tags: r, linux, installation, install.packages

I'm trying to install the fastman function so I can make a manhattan plot. This is my code:

```
install.packages("remotes", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", lib="/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/R")
remotes::install_github("danioreo/fastman",lib = "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/R")
```

and this is my full error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fastman’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: fastman
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/R/fastman’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpP7Gtus/file129f63150195f8/fastman_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've been looking online for help and I haven't found many posts that are related to my problem, and none have solved the issue. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can download the R scripts (https://github.com/danielldhwang/fastman/blob/master/R/fastman.R) and run `source(fastman.R)` from your R/RSudio session.

Source: https://github.com/danielldhwang/fastman/issues/2